# Navigation Route not removed or Pop

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

Currently I am doing a security settings page on my app. Now the issue I am getting is when I am navigating back or pressing back button. The pages are still navigating even pop.

I my code I am using this for going to the first flow

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => otp_mPin())
```

Now on the Second or back flow I have used this

[Code used for second flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgrdg.png)

On the OTP page I used pop it and push

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => mPin())
```

Here is the flow that I am getting

Screen 1 Settings Page

```
 onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProtectPhone()));
              },
```

Screen 2 Page with Password

Navigation for success password

```
   onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context);
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => selectScreenLock()));
          },
```

Back button / willPop

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Screen 3 Selection

Select or click MPin which will redirect to OtpMpin page

```
  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtpMpin())
                );
```

Back or willpop command

```
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProtectPhone())
  );
```

Secreen 4 OTP

Success OTP Input

```
 Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => setMPin()));
```

Screen 5 MPIN

Back or Willpop command

```
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => selectScreenLock())
```

First Flow

1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > 5

Second or back flow

5 > 3 > 2 > 4 > 2 > 1

Comment: before pushing a new page why you are using pop? can you add your all the 5 file navigation code.

Comment: @MSARKrish What i understand on push is it is stacking the pages right I want to the pages to be remove from the stack and replace it. Since pages 3-5 are secured pages and cannot be access without going to page 2 and 4. Wait I will put the navigation codes per page

Comment: you can use Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **pushReplacement** method in 3rd page to 4th page so that while navigating from 3rd page to 4th page, 3rd page is removed from stack and pushed to 4th page. so if user pressing back button in 4th page then user will get second page.

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return NewPage();
            }));
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this

Comment: Yes but on the 5th page when I press back I was redirecting to 4th

Comment: Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => setMPin())); On 4th page

Comment: Should i remove navigator .pop now?

Comment: use pushReplacement in 3rd page because you are said 3rd and 5th pages are important user go to that page by 2nd and 4th page, so use this in 3rd page alone. if you have 6th page then use this method in 5th page.